# Code Runner extension working bad alongside Conda

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda3, vscode-code-runner

I installed and configured VS Code for Python + Conda + Code-Runner but whenever I run code in terminal with the code runner option the first start never gets the conda environment with the libraries I installed, just as below:

[The confusion made when running with code runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8EF9.png)

But the weird part is: when I run it for the second time it works perfectly, just as shown below:

[The second execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19DEG.png)

And the weirdest of all this situation is when I run it again with code runner, the input function takes the input name as the path name of the python file:

[The third execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJaFy.png)

My guess is that there's something going on with this code runner config in my settings.json:

[my code runner config in settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt27q.png)

Or something's up with my paths of conda and python, such as below:

[My conda and python respective paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTEFG.png)

**I wanted to know whats the cause for this events occurring and how exactly I can fix them.**

**DISCLAIMER:** Although there's a folder called "PycharmProjects/", this one there's nothing to do with anything related to Pycharm, it's just a folder I create when I thought using Pycharm but I just didn't deleted it.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I wanted to know are these things happening and how I can fix them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.